# Insert a line break into a string

Tags: python, string

So I was solving this problem in codingame but when the program puts \n as an input it gets printed  instead of applying a line break

````s
change_count = int(input())

for i in range(change_count):
  raw_change = input()
  extract_info = raw_change.split('|')
  index = int(extract_info[1])
  stringToInsert = extract_info[2]
  words = s
  words = words[:index]+ stringToInsert +words[index:]
  print(words)
  modifiedString = ''.join(words)
  s = modifiedString
print(s)```

================================

Input 
Hello world
4
0|11|!
0|5|,\n
0|7| w
0|10|\n
================================
Output

Hello,
 w worl
d!
````

Comment: Do you mean to say, that as a response to `raw_change=input()`,  you actually type something like `|5|\n` and expect a newline to be inserted in position 5 of `words`, whatever that is? (Next time, please provide a *complete* example, with the necessary input, and actual and expected output, required to reproduce the problem!)

Comment: @TurePålsson Sorry for that but i edited the question as you asked

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72412627/4177009) seems to be the same problem, but it’s not very good as a duplicate-question target...

Comment: `\n` is only recognized in string *literals*, not in strings read from any file (including standard input).  You'll need to process such escape sequences yourself.